# jQuery - $(...).scrollTo is not a function

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Есть такой код:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function() { 
    $(".message_block").scrollTo("#message");   
});
```

но выдает ошибку: `$(...).scrollTo is not a function`, поставил самую новую версию jQuery, что может быть не так?

Comment: а в jquery есть метод scrollTo ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView - есть простой нативный способ

Answer (score 1):

Такого метода действительно нет.

Попробуйте следующее:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#message").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: У меня в блоке `$(".message_block")` несколько блоков `message` (разные id), и Ваш код не всегда пролистывает именно к блоку, а уходит чуть ниже

Comment: А, ну тогда не `#message`, а `.message_block` укажите

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/5909792 ? :)